# Transform SSL .crt to kubernetes inline format

Tags: base64, kubernetes, ssl-certificate, pem, pkix

I have created self-signed user certificates for my kubernetes cluster and now want to distribute respective kubeconfig files to the users.

How to I transform the .crt and .key files I used for the process to kubeconfig inline format?

Here is a redacted sample inline representation of the crt file:

```
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-----------xdTZiS1k1WVFYYUwvNXNRcTFKNXMyVnh1ckRaQ2c5anA4ZlQrMEUzbWwvM1lkTEF0MjI0NG1Ec1MKdFFjM2k5Nk8rM0xFeU90REsraW5vKzB1WnZWZ0lrazZhOG9LS0hxaks5b21oOWg3WjE1UjVwWkxIa3dTVmluYwpLbHZGOUt4WXJrekdidmFiRUZZd0p1ejFTdW02ZkJ4dDQ5THkvWDFKQkZ1K1pnWDFPWjdnM2ZPeGt3WWdtVVBnCmt5Mmx1Zk1MZWI2SzdwOVdkaUxsUFAyRWk4aG9CWTNXQk9UQk1kcXY1Wm01VWpUUm9sZkIrTXZwTEp0ZlFOST0KLS0tLS1FTkQgQ0VSVElGSUNBVEUtLS0tLQo=
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Simply encode it with Base 64 :
`cat mycert.crt | base64 -w0`

Comment: No need for cat. Could simply do: base64 -w0 mycert.crt

Answer (score 17):

Secrets are stored as base64, see:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/

Or the example from here:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/

```
cat server.csr | base64 | tr -d '\n'
```

Comment: This answer seems more appropriate, than the one marked right.

Comment: @SuhasChikkanna what you said is correct.

Answer (score 4):

cat mycert.crt|base64 -w0  better

-w, --wrap=COLS       wrap encoded lines after COLS character (default 76).
                          Use 0 to disable line wrapping

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of the accepted answer. Does this answer actually add any extra information?