# Get base64 encoded value for my certificate (to be used in k8s secret manifest)

Tags: kubernetes, openssl, base64, ssl-certificate

I use OpenSSL & generated self signed certificate & key files.

Now I try to transform them to base64 encoded value in order to put into kubernetes "Secret" manifest. I tried [the answer from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48341240/transform-ssl-crt-to-kubernetes-inline-format).

But the accepted answer doesn't work for me, this is what I get:

```
cat myapp.com.crt | base64 -w0
base64: invalid argument -w0
Usage:  base64 [-hDd] [-b num] [-i in_file] [-o out_file]
  -h, --help     display this message
  -Dd, --decode   decodes input
  -b, --break    break encoded string into num character lines
  -i, --input    input file (default: "-" for stdin)
  -o, --output   output file (default: "-" for stdout)
```

Why is that? How to get the base64 encoded value for my certificate so that I can use the value in k8s secret manifest?

Comment: Did you try this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48341521/6453080

Answer (score 1):

What kind of distro are you using? It seems that your `base64` binary is not the same program as used in your referenced answer.

On Ubuntu (20.04) it should work:

```
base64 --help
Usage: base64 [OPTION]... [FILE]
Base64 encode or decode FILE, or standard input, to standard output.

With no FILE, or when FILE is -, read standard input.

Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.
  -d, --decode          decode data
  -i, --ignore-garbage  when decoding, ignore non-alphabet characters
  -w, --wrap=COLS       wrap encoded lines after COLS character (default 76).
                          Use 0 to disable line wrapping

      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit
```

Or you can just use `cat server.csr | base64 | tr -d '\n'` as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48341521/20424756).

Answer (score -1):

You can simply specify the files as parameters for the `kubectl create secret tls` command. You can find more explanations and examples in the [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#tls-secrets).

Comment: This answer is essentially just a link to the documentation.  Can you [edit] it to include enough details that it stands alone?

Answer (score -1):

No need to cat, you can simply do this

```
base64 -w0 your-cert.crt
```